# How to assign texture coordinates in a for loop at OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, gpu

I want to modify the code snippet below in such a way, that I want to generate the geometry with a particular texture using for-loops. I want to input the vertex coordinates, and the amount of vertices and then generate texture planes using glVertex3f. Is this possible?

Edit: To clarify, I want to be able to give the information contained in

```
        glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
        glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
        glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);
```

segment using a for-loop. It's like I'd like to have a glVertex3f[n] array with the coordinates given by the user.

```
// Obstacle texture

// draw with different ppm file
obstProg->enable();
obstProg->bindTexture("tex", obstTex, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
obstProg->bindTexture("shadowTex", renderer->getShadowTexture(), GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
obstProg->setUniformfv("lightPosEye", renderer->getLightPositionEyeSpace(), 3);
obstProg->setUniformfv("lightColor", lightColor, 3);

    // set shadow matrix as texture matrix
matrix4f shadowMatrix3 = renderer->getShadowMatrix();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadMatrixf((GLfloat *) shadowMatrix3.get_value());

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
{
    float rep = 10.f;
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(1, -1, 1);

    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, -1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(1, -1, -1);

    glTexCoord2f(0.f, 0.f); glVertex3f(-1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, 0.f); glVertex3f(1, 1, -1);
    glTexCoord2f(rep, rep); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.f, rep); glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1);

}
glEnd();
obstProg->disable();
```

Comment: You should not use nor learn using immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd, glTexCoord, glVertex and some others). They have been *removed* from OpenGL-3 and later. And they're clumsy to use.

Comment: Thanks for advise. But is there any way to perform the act I described in my question?

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: Considering that you haven't described exactly what you're trying to do very well... no. You say you want to "generate texture planes". Well, what is a "texture plane?" Is that like a "texture coordinate?" How do you intend to generate this "texture plane?"

Comment: @Nicol Balas: Sorry for the wording. That's because I'm a newbie and not familiar with the terminology. I want to write glTexCoord2f and glVertex3f lines in a loop, specifying the coordinates with an array. That's all I want.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: So... do that. What do you need from us?

Comment: @Nicol Balas: The problem is that the number of glVertex3f lines may also change because I want to input that also.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: Here's an idea: try it, see what happens, and then ask us if you can't figure out why it's broken.

Comment: @EmreTurkoz: Since you already have the vertex data in a array it makes sense to send them to OpenGL directly, instead of manually looping over them and call immediate mode functions. Google for "Vertex Arrays"

Comment: @Nicol Balas: Sorry, how can I give the number of glVertex3f entities and fill them? That's my question.

Comment: @datenwolf: thank you so much. I'd like to accept your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the vertex data in a array it makes sense to send them to OpenGL directly, instead of manually looping over them and call immediate mode functions. Google for "Vertex Arrays"